# C++ Armadillo: GCC vs VC++2013: Operator () and overloading

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading, armadillo

I'm trying to develop a Linux/Win64 application using the Armadillo C++ library.  The following code compiles in GCC-4.7, but fails to compile in Visual Studio 2013 using the Armadillo provided VS project file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "armadillo"

using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

//works in GCC-4.7
//VC++2013: compile error: C3066
void foo1(vec::fixed<4> &bar)
{
    bar(1) = 1.;
}

//works
void foo2(vec::fixed<4> &bar)
{
    bar.at(2) = 1.;
}

//works
void foo3(vec &bar)
{
    bar(3) = 1.;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << "Armadillo version: " << arma_version::as_string() << endl;
    vec::fixed<4> bar;
    bar.zeros();
    foo1(bar);
    foo2(bar);
    foo3(bar);
    cout << "Bar: " << bar << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error ocurs with function `foo1`:

```
1>example1.cpp(11): error C3066: there are multiple ways that an object of this type can be called with these arguments
1>          ../armadillo_bits/Col_bones.hpp(186): could be 'const arma::subview_col<eT> arma::Col<eT>::operator ()(const arma::span &) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              eT=double
1>          ]
1>          ../armadillo_bits/Col_bones.hpp(186): or       'arma::subview_col<eT> arma::Col<eT>::operator ()(const arma::span &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              eT=double
1>          ]
1>          ../armadillo_bits/Col_bones.hpp(186): or       'double &arma::Mat<double>::operator ()(const arma::uword)'
1>          ../armadillo_bits/Col_bones.hpp(186): or       'const double &arma::Mat<double>::operator ()(const arma::uword) const'
1>          ../armadillo_bits/Col_bones.hpp(205): or       'double &arma::Col<double>::fixed<4>::operator ()(const arma::uword)'
1>          ../armadillo_bits/Col_bones.hpp(206): or       'const double &arma::Col<double>::fixed<4>::operator ()(const arma::uword) const'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(int)'
```

Obviously I want the second to last choice here, and the others should not apply based on type inference.  GCC seems to agree, so there must be something different about how VC++ resolves these overloaded operators?  Interestingly things resolve if I use the `.at()` method as in foo2.  But `.at()` is overloaded in nearly the same pattern of methods, so why does that work?  I run into related problems with operator= in my actual code, so I suspect there is something special about operators here.  Are there any non-ugly ways to fix this issue?  I'd like to use the normal `operator()` instead of method `.at()`.

Comment: Just as an additional data point, what does Clang say?

Comment: It compiles fine under Clang 3.4. This looks like a bug in MS VC++, as the first suggestion is clearly bogus ("_... could be const arma::subview_col<eT> arma::Col<eT>::operator ()(const arma::span &) const_"). Looking at Armadillo source, there is no implicit conversion between the integer argument 1 and `arma::span`. See line 58 in include/armadillo_bits/span.hpp, where the relevant constructor for the `span` class is marked as `explicit`. The other suggestions by MS VC++ are bogus as well, as the `Col::fixed` class inherits from the `Col` class and redefines `operator()`.

Comment: This is indeed a MSVC bug where `explicit` is being ignored; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498142/visual-studio-2013-explicit-keyword-bug for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to [MSVC connect bug #811334](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811334/bug-in-vs-2013-support-for-explicit-conversion-operators) as per the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498142/visual-studio-2013-explicit-keyword-bug) Ryan linked in his comment here, and should be fixed in MSVC 2015.

(The bug is that MSVC is ignoring the `explicit` keyword on the constructor -- it's related to the linked SO post's code, but not quite the same, as the linked SO post and report deal with the lossage of `explicit` on conversion operators.)